# Error on migrating Queries from one Account to another using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

When creating the queries on the new account I'm getting this error for all of my queries that have the Data Action set as **Update**:

```
Error saving the Query field.The Target Data Extension must have at least one primary key field.
```

The problem is that all of the Data Extensions have one or more primary keys.

Any ideas of why is this happening?

Comment: The error suggests that the Data Extension in the a account you're trying to create the Query in does not have a Primary Key defined. Update queries require the target data extension to have a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
For some reason when doing the query retrieve from the old account it was not returning the correct CustomerKey for these specific DEs(qry.DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey), so I just added a retrieve for the DE using the name(qry.DataExtensionTarget.Name) and it worked perfectly.